# bash one-liner while loop to ssh into internal IP or external IP

Tags: bash, ssh

I would like to have a while loop on my terminal screen that tries to ssh into my server every second. At the moment it looks something like this:

```
while true; do echo INTERNALIP && date >> $HOME/server.log &&\
    ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@192.168.1.10;\
     date;\
sleep 1; done
```

I have a similar bash `while` loop for sshing into the same machine, but using the external IP, which is the way I connect when I am not in the office network:

```
while true; do echo EXTERNALIP && date >> $HOME/server.log &&\
    ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@NN.NNN.NN.NNN;\
     date;\
sleep 1; done
```

What I would like to do is to consolidate both of these into a single one-liner, that (1) first tries to connect via the INTERNALIP, and if that fails, then tries to connect via the EXTERNALIP. I am not too familiar with conditionals in bash, so I am not sure how to do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your script does exactly what you want, I would run something like this:

```
while true; do echo INTERNALIP && date >> $HOME/server.log && \
    if [ "`find .external.pid -mtime 1 | egrep '.*'`" == "" ]; then \
        ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@192.168.1.10; \
        if [ $? == 255 ]; then touch -d "-1 day" .external.pid; fi; \
    else ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@NN.NNNN.NN.NNN; \
        if [ $? == 255 ]; then rm .external.pid; fi; \
    fi; \
    date; \
sleep 1; done
```

This use a .external.pid to keep track of which server should be used.

PS: You would probably use this instead:

```
while true; do echo INTERNALIP && date >> $HOME/server.log && \
    if [ "`find .external.pid -atime +1s | egrep '.*'`" == "" ]; then \
        ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 -o user@192.168.1.10 'date'; \
        if [ $? == 255 ]; then touch .external.pid; fi; \
    else ssh -Y -o ServerAliveInterval=5 -o ServerAliveCountMax=1 user@NN.NNNN.NN.NNN 'date'; \
        if [ $? == 255 ]; then rm .external.pid; fi; \
    fi; \
sleep 1; done
```

Comment: In Linux, I am getting this error `find: unknown predicate '-x'`

Comment: I updated the code removing the "-x": it doesn't affect final result

Comment: atime is also different in Linux than macosx

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the following line inside your loop:

```
ssh user@192.168.1.10 || ssh user@NN.NNN.NN.NNN
```

The way I understand this only if the ssh to 192.168.1.10 fails then the second ssh will be triggered. Isn't that what you want?

I left out all the other details of ssh options,  logs etc.

Even better maybe something like this:

```
( ssh user@192.168.1.10 && echo INTERNALIP ) || ( ssh user@NN.NNN.NN.NNN && echo EXTERNALIP )
```

This ought to take care of the logs as well & is a one liner. (Don't have a chance to test it right now so be warned. )